# Remove "public/" from URL

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

### The scenario

I have a script to upload a file to a directory and I need to return its path but without `public/` prefix.

The upload destination is: `public/uploads/`, but I just need the `uploads/` part.

### The puzzle

I need `public/` to upload the image because it is the physical directory which the image will be placed. So, how can I remove it (with a great approach) when I retrieve the path?

### In practice

My final upload → `/public/uploads/1.jpg`

I want to retrieve → `/uploads/1.jpg`

### Thoughts

I think I can remove the first part of the URL with the following *snippet*:

```
final_directory = directory.split('public/')[1]
```

But I don't feel comfortable by doing this.

Do you have anything better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think at the time of upload all files will be uploaded to the `/public/uploads/` path.

When you fetch the file and show it, you can simply use the `/uploads/` path. This is working for me.

Comment: Are you suggesting me to create something like a constant to handle with `public` word?

Comment: I think in a rails application all files inside Public directory are called first, all files in that directory have the highest priority. So you just only need to mention it at the time of upload only.